# html datalist item not getting the selected value changed after a single click in IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown, html-datalist

I am using HTML Datalist, it works well in Chrome. but in **IE**, it's not working as expected.

**Problem:** after selecting any of the options, it's coming with a 'x' labeled-link at the end.Ideally, it should take the selected value, but it's not taking. we need to click somewhere outside then it's taking.

**Expectation:** there needs a function triggering onchange of the value, which currently not able to achieve smoothly(since it needs to click somewhere outside to let the event take place).

Here is my sample code :

```html
    <html>
    <body>

    <form>
      <input list="browsers" name="browser" onchange="callFunction()">
      <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="Internet Explorer">
        <option value="Firefox">
        <option value="Chrome">
        <option value="Opera">
        <option value="Safari">
      </datalist>
    </form>
    </body>

<script>
function callFunction(){
alert("onchange got triggered");
}
</script>
    </html>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you're aiming to do.

Comment: the problem occurs when we open the page in IE, lets put an function triggering on onchange of the values in the dropdown. Copy paste this code and open in IE11 to reproduce the issue

Comment: still not clear...

Comment: editted now, just open it in IE 11 to reproduce the issue. the onchange event is not taking up after selecting the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have:

```
...

</body>

<script>
function callFunction(){
alert("onchange got triggered");
}
</script>
</html>
```

I don't believe that's valid HTML, and it maybe tripping up certain web browsers.  Try putting the `<script>...</script>` within `<body>...</body>`.

```
...

<script>
function callFunction(){
alert("onchange got triggered");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have corrected that, but the issue not related to that actually. Probably the IE 11 has issue while rendering to the datalist drop-down. Please open this page in IE 11 and select any option value to reproduce the problem (The onchange triggering is not happening, if we click somewhere outside then only it gets invoked)